# Copy output of the program to the screen and also to the file

Tags: c, linux

I have written client-server application in C. I run the server in linux. 
I need to do simple logs of what server do. I print it to the screen. 
Please how can I copy output of the screen also to the file.
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) command as:

```
./server_program | tee server.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tee` command:

```
$ ./program | tee log.txt
```